# R.java Error when adding new layouts

Tags: android, android-manifest

// Activity1.java

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
```

// AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity android:name=".Activity3"
          android:label="@string/page2">
    </activity>
```

These are the lines that show an error.

I am trying to use Intent and move from page 1->2->3

this the button code

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Did you add your new activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these 2 lines too within application tags in your manifest.xml file

```
  <application>
  .....

 <activity android:name=".Activity2" />
 <activity android:name=".Activity3" />

 ....

 </application>
```

Comment: i had renames app_name to myapp. guess that creates an error.

Comment: :) ahan that happens with me too sometimes :D

Answer (score 1):

Add Ur activity names (2 activites) to manifest file. and here i have taken like